# session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88

Tags: python, selenium

I installed the version `chromedriver 88` as requested but my version chrome is `87.0.4280.88` that is the last version (outside beta)

while I am also asked to download `version 88` of `chrome`

**Here is the error** :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88
Current browser version is 87.0.4280.88 with binary path 
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Some years ago, I was never poked like this just because a new version of google chrome came out. I could keep the same chromedriver for ages.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your ChromeDriver version and your installed version of Chrome need to match up. You are using ChromeDriver for Chrome version 87.
Keep both version same.

Check your Chrome version (Help -> About) and then find the correct ChromeDriver release. You could instead use webdriver-manager which can handle this for you.

`Chrome is 87.0.4280.88`

`ChromeDriver Version 87`

download from here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=87.0.4280.88/

Comment: Instead of *down*grading one's version of ChromeDriver to match the Chrome version......isn't there a way to do the opposite....i.e. *up*grade one's version of Chrome inside the puppeteer folder to match the latest version of ChromeDriver?  I'm not a big fan of downgrading stuff.

Comment: @CadeBryant Yes either you downgrade chromeDriver version or update Chrome browser any way you have to keep both on same page (same version).

Answer (score 17):

you can also use it through webdriver manager, check the chrome version by going to about in chrome and specify the version of compatible chromedriver as version argument

Install manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Use with Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version="87.0.4280.88").install())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: This is such a great solution for this problem that exists EVERY time I goto build a new Selenium/python application.

Comment: I cannot find webdriver_manager.   There is a webdriver-manager that matches.

Comment: I don't see how this helps... just a wrapper method, and you still have to know what driver version you need

Comment: @Adjit in CI/CD you can pass the chrome version as command line argument and thus don't have to manually install the chrome driver

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this as well in R. One way to deal with this is to specify the Chromedriver version you want to use. So, if your Chrome browser version is 87.0.4280.88, you can specify the corresponding Chromedriver version by the `chromever` argument.

In R it is done like this (and I believe it is similar for Python):

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "87.0.4280.88")
```

Answer (score 2):

this type of error: `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89 Current browser version is 88.0.4324.190 ...` occurs when the version of the SELENIUM controller differs from the version of the web browser that we currently have or are trying to use, from the code that we are programming, some parameters can be indicated to force certain configurations in the execution from our program remotely: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/remote_webdriver/remote_webdriver_client/, another way we have is according to the error message we can see the Selenium version and the browser version we have, With that information we can then enter: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html where we can see all the existing versions of the Chrome Driver, download the one we need and call it from the function that we are configuring, without need to upgrade or downgrade the browser directly.

Below the images to understand better, greetings!

[image: Repo ChromeDriver]
[image: Correct Version]

I hope it is useful, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

find your chrome version here: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-version-of-chrome-do-i-have
and download the webdriver here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your browser needs to match the driver. So for a Python question, a python answer:

Using pip install/upgrade webdrivermanager:

```
pip install --upgrade webdrivermanager
```

Install/set the version of the driver compatible with your chrome version:

```
# webdrivermanager <browser>:<version> -l <location of the webdrivers in your path>, e.g.:
webdrivermanager chromedriver:87.0 -l C:/path/to/your/drivers
```

It should now work.

This method is easy to use and works for multiple types of drivers, which to date are: `chrome, firefox, gecko, mozilla, opera, edge, edgechromium`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to specify the chrome version you are using:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 87.0.4280.88
```